# Fowarding a ref with mobx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react-lite

i am trying to build a custom component video player with react and mobx, and i need to drill a refrence from a main component to a child Component but i'm getting an error message when i use the forwardRef function on a component that is an observer.
the error message is "baseComponent is not a function"
Here's the code:

```
// code for main component
const videoPlayer = () => {

const controlsRef = useRef<any>(null);

return (<div>
// video player screen code //
<VideoPlayerButtonCode ref={controlsRef} />
<div>)

}

// the code for the players component

interface IProps{
 controlsRef: any;
}

const VideoPlayerButtonCode: React.FC<IProps> = fowardRef({props from iprops}, controlsRef ) => {

return (<div>

<Button ref={controlsRef}>Button i want to get a ref for from main</Button>
<div>)

}

export default observer(VideoPlayerButtonCode)
```

thats a vague abstraction of the code but the same implementation.
is there any help for mobx supports for ref or is there a way i can store the refrence in a mobx store?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What version of `mobx-react` are you using? It should work fine with latest 7.0.0 version, but it seems to fail if you are using `mobx-react-lite@3.0.0`.

I've made codesandbox with all working variants as for now: https://codesandbox.io/s/httpsstackoverflowcomquestions64227496-75xdz?file=/src/App.js

For example same version as your works fine:

```
const ComponentWithForwardRef = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return <div ref={ref}>My Observer Component</div>;
});

const ObserverComponentWithForwardRef = observer(ComponentWithForwardRef);
```

There is also a `forwardRef` option for `observer` HOC, but it only currently works with `mobx-react-lite`, and does not work with regular `mobx-react` package due to this bug https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react/issues/868

You can use it like that:

```
const MyObserverComponent = observer(
  (props, ref) => {
    return <div ref={ref}>My Observer Component</div>;
  },
  { forwardRef: true }
);
```

If everything fails you can just use custom prop for your ref like so:

```
<MyObserverComponentCustomRef innerRef={myRef} />

// ...

const MyObserverComponentCustomRef = observer((props) => {
  return <div ref={props.innerRef}>My Observer Component Inner Ref</div>;
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much it turns out it was the version